# How to solve the recurrence relation of Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, chebyshev-polynomials

The Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind are obtained from the recurrence relation
$$\begin{aligned}T_{0}(x)&=1\\T_{1}(x)&=x\\T_{n+1}(x)&=2x\,T_{n}(x)-T_{n-1}(x)~.\end{aligned}$$
Is it possible to solve this recurrence relation?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions) any good?

Comment: @J.G., thank you. I can't understand how these expression can be obtained

Comment: It's probably easier to start from $T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos n\theta$, which implies the recursion relation.